# Error: Uncaught (in promise): [object Object].Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to create an upload button with angular 5, I'm using this code in my .ts file:

```
    handleFiles(e) {
    this.file = e.srcElement.files[0];
    if (this.file.size > 2097152) {
      let snackBarRef = this.snackBar.open('Images must be 2 MB or less', 'OK!', {
        duration: 3000
      });
    } else {
      this.uploadImage();
    }
  }

  uploadImage() {
    let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
    let path = Date.now().toString() + '-' + this.file.name;
    let iRef = storageRef.child('posts/' + path);
    let me = this;
    iRef.put(this.file).then((snapshot) => {
        let snackBarRef = this.snackBar.open('Image uploaded', 'OK!', {
          duration: 3000
        });
        this.storageRef.child('posts/' + path).getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
          me.imageUrl = url;
          me.newThumbnail = url;
        });
    });
  }
```

I got this error in my console: **Error: Uncaught (in promise): [object Object]**.

Any ideas about this issue please? because I couldn't find nothing when debugging.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have to handle the error in the promises.

```
iRef.put(this.file).then((snapshot) => {
    let snackBarRef = this.snackBar.open('Image uploaded', 'OK!', {
      duration: 3000
    });
    this.storageRef.child('posts/' + path).getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
      me.imageUrl = url;
      me.newThumbnail = url;
    })
    .catch( error => { console.error(error) })
})
.catch( error => {
   console.error(error);
})
```

So you will be able to see what is happening, and where.

Comment: still same as before, any ideas about the error? what is all about?

Comment: Are you sure this error is being thrown because of this block of code?

Comment: Yes I debuged the code the error shows when this code is executed

Comment: And to which of those 2 promises does this error belongs?

Comment: I found it, all i needed was just adding             var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(newFirebaseSrcVal); before storing the Url, it works perfectly now, thank you very much for your help @Christian.